# How to create a JID from the Username

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

I've been running the echo.html example that comes with [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/). When I start it up I sign in using a user I made called **user1**. When I click the connect button I get the following output:

```
Strophe is connecting.
Strophe is connected.
ECHOBOT: Send a message to 5ee09j8v8y@ubuntu/5ee09j8v8y to talk to me.
```

I am able to successfully test this example using the [Gajim](https://gajim.org/) client. In Gajim I simply start a new chat using the above JID (5ee09j8v8y@ubuntu/5ee09j8v8y). When I send a message using Gajim it shows up on the echobot example and everything is hunky dory.

**So here's my question**, I see from [this](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0029.html) official site that the JID is in this format:

```
<JID> ::= [<node>"@"]<domain>["/"<resource>]
```

And I get that the resource is [optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/855050/3299397), and that the domain in my case above is simply my computer's name (my computer's name is **ubuntu**). BUT what I don't get is how the heck you get **5ee09j8v8y** from the username **user1**.

The code inside echobot.js which prints the JID line above uses this command to get the information:

```
connection.jid
```

Which is just a [Strophe.Connection Object](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.0.2/files2/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.Strophe.Connection) retrieving it's JID.

**So to sum all of this up**, I cannot communicate from Gajim using `user1@ubuntu/5ee09j8v8y` the only way it works is when I use the JID `5ee09j8v8y@ubuntu/5ee09j8v8y`. So what exactly is the node (5ee09j8v8y), how does it get mapped to the username (user1), how can I get Gajim to work with `user1@ubuntu/5ee09j8v8y` instead of using `5ee09j8v8y@ubuntu/5ee09j8v8y` and at the very least can someone point me in the right direction to some documentation on this JID problem?

Note: [This](https://expertnotfound.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/setting-up-openfire-bosh-strophe/) tutorial will explain my setup (and help others who are curious in how I set all of this up).

Comment: Check my previous answers on SO, maybe the examples could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510219/chat-functionality-in-web-application-using-xmpp-and-openfire/34524981#34524981, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994662/strophe-register-plugin/35055565#35055565, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292181/complete-example-of-strophe-js-file-transfer/35358428#35358428